# Postresql replication pg_basebackup no pg_hbaconf entry for replication connection

Tags: postgresql

I have updated my `pg_hba.conf` on the master to this.

```
host    loko     replicator      10.0.2.15/32               trust
```

and I did reload the configuration.  Then I created a user with this command

```
 CREATE USER replicator REPLICATION LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'repl'
```

`loko` which is the database on my master and `replicator` as the user.

and running this command on the slave

```
pg_basebackup -h x.x.x.x -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\data" -U 
replicator -v -P --write-recovery-conf -X stream
```

results in

```
no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host x.x.x.x. user replicator, SSL off
```

Thanks a lot for any help. Im new to this so I don't have any idea whats wrong with this. I just followed a tutorial.

Answer (score 7):

You have to grant access in replication in `pg_hba.conf`.
Here's the line you should add:

```
host    replication     replicator      10.0.2.15/32               trust
```

You will find documentation here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Here's the phrase that explain everything:

> The value `replication` specifies that the record matches if a replication connection is requested (note that replication connections do not specify any particular database).

Comment: Yes, physical replication in PG 9.x uses WAL streaming. And the WAL contains all changes for all databases in a cluster. Hence specifying a database for the replication connection would make no sense, and that position is used for the `replication` keyword. I guess this also means you can't have a database called "replication".

Comment: Yes you can! (But I don't how you could possibly use that database in pg_hba.conf)

postgres=# create database replication;
CREATE DATABASE

Comment: you would just quote it (ex: "replication"). From the documentation: "Quoting one of the keywords in a database, user, or address field (e.g., all or replication) makes the word lose its special meaning, and just match a database, user, or host with that name."